# management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders PassthroughTokenValidationFailed Error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-entra-id

I'm trying to list reservation orders for a dummy customer on microsoft azure portal sandbox.
The customer has already an azure plan and a reserved instance subscription.
I was able to consent the application with which I try to access
GET: [https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders?api-version={{api_version}}](https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders?api-version=%7B%7Bapi_version%7D%7D)
All of the relevant permissions are granted to the application accessing my tenant's directory.

I'm also able to get an authentication token. But when I request the URL in the title, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "PassthroughTokenValidationFailed",
        "message": "Token validation failed. A passthrough token was detected without proper resource provider context - request correlation identifier 'correlation id'"
    }
}
```

Any ideas about this kind of error ? I did not find any relevant resources neither on microsoft forums nor here.

I tried to get a token from my customer azure AD. Which I did.
I expected the token to work properly. But it didn't.
Getting "PassthroughTokenValidationFailed" when prompting a GET api from Microsoft.Capacity

Comment: Could you include how you are generating the token with what authentication flow like client credentials or any other?

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. I'm using a client ID and a client secret from my app to generate a token. In jwt.ms appidacr=1

Comment: Are you using tools like Postman while generating token?What RBAC roles service principal has under subscription?

Comment: Hi, I'm generating the token in a web based application not in postman. My admin account has "Owner" and "User access administrator" roles. But the service principal has no RBAC. I will add Owner RBAC and check if it helps.

Comment: Could you include the code you are using to generate the token by editing your question?

Comment: The service principal is now owner of the azure subscription but still receiveing the same PassthroughTokenValidationFailed error.

Comment: The error message seems to be related to token generation. Please edit your question by including the code to know what authentication flow you used to acquire token

Comment: @Sridevi The limitation I have is that I'm not owner of the code. I only have access to the tenant azure Entra ID. No reported issues on our prod env. So figuring this has to be something with azure tenant config.

Comment: @Sridevi I can provide you with jwt.ms info as I decrypt the token. Let me know what fields you may need.

Comment: Could you confirm what values you got for aud, iss, roles or scp fields?

Comment: here aud https://management.azure.com || iss https://sts.windows.net//{{guid}} || have no roles field || scp user_impersonation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ***"PassthroughTokenValidationFailed"*** usually occurs due to passthrough sign-ins that is if the user does not have the access to the tenant. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/concept-sign-ins#special-considerations).

I created an Azure AD application and granted API permissions:

[image]

I tried to login with the user account that exists in the tenant:

[image]

Generated **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Make sure to decode the access token and check the below:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check the below:

- Assign reader role to the user you are using to sign-in.
- Or assign reader role to the service principal.
- Make use of other user account to generate the token and call the API.

Comment: Hello Naveen, thanks for your help. After adding the proper authorization to the remote user. I don't have the passthrough token error anymore. But I have the following error "AuthorizationFailed...does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/read' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Capacity' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.". Although in my azure subscription IAM I did define the user as Owner of the subscription. Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi, the problem is solved. Although the reservation roles were connfigured via the GUI of Azure Portal, I needed to do it via powershell: PS /home/{user}> New-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/providers/Microsoft.Capacity" -PrincipalId {Target-user-ObjectId}  -RoleDefinitionName "Reservations Administrator"